# How to route child resources on Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

So I writing a simple app that has nested resources: posts and comments. Naturally, posts are parents, comments are children, related each one to one post. Simple enough. Now I want comments index (and creation, POST) page to live at `posts/{post_id}/comments`, update (PUT) to live at `/posts/{post_id}/comments/{comment_id}`. So I tried this:

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'posts/{post_id}'), function() {
    Route::resource('comments', 'CommentsController');
});
```

But it won't work since the route name is registered as `posts.{post_id}.comments.create`. Basically the post_id placeholder is counted as part of the route and it's not neat. Any way of doing this nicely or should I just write routes one by one and get rid of the group/Route::resource/prefix thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use nested resources like this;

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
Route::resource('posts.comments', 'CommentsController');
```

When you `php artisan routes` you will see your new routes;

```
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                                             | Name                   | Action                             | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET|HEAD posts                                  | posts.index            | PostsController@index              |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD posts/create                           | posts.create           | PostsController@create             |                |               |
|        | POST posts                                      | posts.store            | PostsController@store              |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD posts/{posts}                          | posts.show             | PostsController@show               |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD posts/{posts}/edit                     | posts.edit             | PostsController@edit               |                |               |
|        | PUT posts/{posts}                               | posts.update           | PostsController@update             |                |               |
|        | PATCH posts/{posts}                             |                        | PostsController@update             |                |               |
|        | DELETE posts/{posts}                            | posts.destroy          | PostsController@destroy            |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD posts/{posts}/comments                 | posts.comments.index   | CommentsController@index           |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD posts/{posts}/comments/create          | posts.comments.create  | CommentsController@create          |                |               |
|        | POST posts/{posts}/comments                     | posts.comments.store   | CommentsController@store           |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD posts/{posts}/comments/{comments}      | posts.comments.show    | CommentsController@show            |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD posts/{posts}/comments/{comments}/edit | posts.comments.edit    | CommentsController@edit            |                |               |
|        | PUT posts/{posts}/comments/{comments}           | posts.comments.update  | CommentsController@update          |                |               |
|        | PATCH posts/{posts}/comments/{comments}         |                        | CommentsController@update          |                |               |
|        | DELETE posts/{posts}/comments/{comments}        | posts.comments.destroy | CommentsController@destroy         |                |               |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Comment: When I write something like this in CommentsController ```index($posts){ echo $posts}```, It doesn't display anything?